# How to make an Array of this elements

Tags: javascript

I need a little help,
How can I make an **Array of the elements**...

```
var end1 = new Date('11/28/2013 10:10 AM');
var end2 = new Date('11/30/2013 10:10 AM');
var end2 = new Date('11/29/2013 10:10 AM');

var ends = [end1, end2, end3];
```

Is that right?
thanks!!!!

Comment: Yes that is an array of date objects

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place for asking if your code is right. Why don't you try and run it, and then determine for yourself if it is right. If it doesn't work (which it will) then you can come back and detail the specific problem, including any error messages you have

Comment: When I put this array into a loop and try to get the value it gives me a NaN ERROR.

Comment: So click "edit" and add your loop code and we can probably tell you what the problem is. (And fix the typo: you have two `end2` variables declared.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct, but you can simplify it by writing

```
var ends = [new Date('11/28/2013 10:10 AM'),
        new Date('11/30/2013 10:10 AM'),
        new Date('11/29/2013 10:10 AM')];
```

Comment: I think your answer won't be a best practice

Comment: Why would this be considered bad practice?

Comment: While making new array of elements your answer is fine, but while making array from existing element : thats not fine

Comment: The OP seems to be initializing three instances of `Date` solely to add them to the array. In this case, I believe it's better to simply initialize them within the array itself rather than having 3 references hanging around.